# 0からｎまでの総和の結果をすべて出力する方法

Tags: c

このように出力されればいいそうなのですが、

```
$ ./a.out
n: 5
sum( 0) =   0
sum( 1) =   1
sum( 2) =   3
sum( 3) =   6
sum( 4) =  10
sum( 5) =  15
```

自分のプログラムのどこが間違っていますか。

```
int sum(int n)
{
    int s,i;
    s=0;
    for(i=0;i<=n;i=i+1) {
        s=s+i;
    }

    return s;
}

int main(void)
{
    int n,ans;
    printf("n: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    ans=sum(n);
    printf("sum(n)=%d \n",ans);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 質問文にある通りの結果が欲しいのであれば、https://wandbox.org/permlink/3Ha3OgnwOWM8nYB0 の様になりますが、どうなのでしょう？

Comment: 「総和を計算する経過も表示」したいのですよね? 「総和の計算の途中」(`for` ループ) で出力していないのだから、期待(?)通りの出力が得られないのは当然ですよね? 授業か何かの課題ですか?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 自分のプログラムのどこが間違っていますか。

まずは

```
sum( 5) =  15
```

の部分ですね。

```
printf("sum(%d)=%d \n", n, ans);
```

のように 出力する値を複数指定することができます。

printf 関数の 書式は実は複雑なので、よく使う パターンだけは覚えておき
詳細な書式は 必要に応じてマニュアルを読めば使えるようにしておきましょう。

次は 0 から n まで繰り返し計算して出力する方法。

ループの開始、終了に気を付けて、
数値の計算と、計算結果の表示を行います。

```
for(int m = 0; m <= n; m++) {
　//計算 ：sum(m)
　//計算結果の印字 ：printf を使って sum(m) の結果を印字
}
```

のようにします。

Comment: 細かい事を言うと %4d 等を使って 右端をそろえるといいでしょう。